# Upload same name files to google cloud storage then download them with original names

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-api-java-client

So in google-cloud-storage if you upload more than one file with the same name to it the last will overwrite what was uploaded before it.

If I want to upload more than one file with the same name I should append some unique thing to the file name e.g. timestamp, random UUID.

But by doing so I'll lose the original file name while downloading, because I want to serve the file directly from google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we used the unique identifier as a folder instead of appending it to the file name, e.g. `UUID +"/"+ fileName` then we can download the file with its original name.

Answer (score 3):

You could turn on [Object Versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) which will keep the old versions of the object around.

Alternatively, you can set the [Content Disposition](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata#content-disposition) header when uploading the object, which should preserve whatever filename you want on download.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using object versioning, you can attach a UUID (or any other unique identifier) and then update the metadata of the object (specifically the content disposition), the following is a part of a python script i've used to remove a forward slashes - added by google cloud buckets to represent directories, the script is based on this [blog post](https://mziccard.me/2015/05/18/response-content-disposition/), please keep in mind the double quotes around the content position "file name"

```
def update_blob_download_name(bucket_name):
    """ update the download name of blobs and remove
    the path. 
    :returns: None
    :rtype: None
    """
    # Storage client, not added to the code for brevity 
    client = initialize_google_storage_client()
    bucket = client.bucket(bucket_name)
    for blob in bucket.list_blobs():
        if "/" in blob.name:
            remove_path = blob.name[blob.name.rfind("/") + 1:] # rfind gives that last occurence of the char
            ext = pathlib.Path(remove_path).suffix
            remove_id = remove_path[:remove_path.rfind("_id_")]
            new_name = remove_id + ext
            blob.content_disposition = f'attachment; filename="{new_name}"'
            blob.patch()
```